# Why does the axion solve the CP problem?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, cp-violation, axion

I don't understand why the CP violating term in QCD vanishes when we introduce the axion. The term is $$\left(\frac{a}{f_a}+\theta\right)G\tilde{G}$$ It is claimed that $\left\langle a\right\rangle=-\theta f_a$ which cancels the term, but why is the VEV this value?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/326233/why-is-is-the-vacuum-expectation-value-vev-of-the-axion-field-such-that-it-can

Comment: Indeed, answered here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/326233/why-is-is-the-vacuum-expectation-value-vev-of-the-axion-field-such-that-it-can/519669#519669

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is is the vacuum expectation value (VEV) of the axion field such that it cancels the theta angle of QCD?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/326233/why-is-is-the-vacuum-expectation-value-vev-of-the-axion-field-such-that-it-can)